# Three20 API Integration Problem

Tags: iphone, three20

Three20/Three20.h:No such file or directory

I am getting this error when after following all steps found at this link:
https://github.com/facebook/three20/
I guess the problem with the header search path which i set as:
../three20/Build/Products/three20

Do i need to take care of the Three20 framework's directory?
please advise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the following resources:

- [Three20 From the Ground Up Episode #1: Building Three20 for the first time](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0-E-Z0fihg)
- [Add Three20 to your project](http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-Adding-Three20-To-Your-Project)

Comment: hi i appreciate...I followed above link....
but terminal does not recognise "git clone"...i am not used to terminal...is there any specific thing I need to do??
I created a separate folder and used cd command to navigate into it through terminal and when i typed git clone https://github.com/facebook/three20.git
terminal does not recognise the git command...